# Integral constant passed by value, treated as constexpr?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, constexpr

Although I've used code like this before, and it's clear that the compiler has enough information to work, I don't really understand why this compiles:

```
template <class T, class I>
auto foo(const T& t, I i) {
    return std::get<i>(t);
}

int main()
{
    std::cerr << foo(std::make_tuple(3,4), std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>{});
    return 0;
}
```

Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc9cc6b954912bc5.

Seems to work with both gcc and clang. The thing is that while `integral_constant` has a `constexpr` conversion to the stored integer, `constexpr` member functions implicitly take the object itself as an argument, and therefore such a function cannot be used in a `constexpr` context unless the object we're calling the member function itself can be treated as `constexpr`.

Here, `i` is an argument passed to `foo`, and therefore `i` most certainly cannot be treated as `constexpr`. Yet, it is. An even simpler example:

```
template <class I>
void foo(I i) {
    constexpr std::size_t j = i;
}
```

This compiles too, as long as `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>{}` is passed to `foo`.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious about the `constexpr` rules. Is there an exception for stateless types, or something else? (or, maybe, a compiler bug in two major compilers? This code seems to work on clang 5 and gcc 7.2).

Edit: an answer has been posted, but I don't think it's quite sufficient. In particular, given the last definition of `foo`, why does:

```
foo(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>{});
```

Compile, but not:

```
foo(0);
```

Both 0 and `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>{}` are constant expressions.

Edit 2: It seems like it boils down to the fact that calling a `constexpr` member function even on an object that is not a constant expression, can itself be regarded as a constant expression, as long as `this` is unused. This is being taken as obvious. I don't consider this obvious:

```
constexpr int foo(int x, int y) { return x; }

constexpr void bar(int y) { constexpr auto x = foo(0, y); }
```

This does not compile, because `y` as passed into `foo` is not a constant expression. It's being unused does not matter. Therefore, a complete answer needs to show some kind of language from the standard to justify the fact that a `constexpr` member function can be used as a constant expression, even on a non-constant expression object, as long as `this` is unused.

Comment: Works on Visual C++ too: https://godbolt.org/g/Cknxco

Comment: Seems to fail on the intel compiler: https://godbolt.org/g/wLc5dw

Comment: @Justin Good catch although given that it's icc I'm betting it's another unrelated bug :-).

Comment: This is interesting; [it can be used to implement an `operator[]` for `std::tuple`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/T1fnX3xG4CrINfEh), and combining it with some sort of integral-constant literal would make it even clearer (`tuple[0_c]`).

Comment: This is a shorter explanation: `i` is not constexpr, but `I` has a consexpr cast operator to `int`. Your code is equivalent to `    return std::get<I{}>(t);` or `    return std::get<I::value>(t);`, which is a common idiom. Cheers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The rules for compile time constant expressions changed with `constexpr`, A LOT, but they aren't new.  Before `constexpr`, there were already compile time constant expressions... and the old rules are preserved as special cases in the new specification, to avoid breaking huge amounts of existing code.

For the most part, the old rules dealt with compile-time constants of integral type aka *integral constant expression*... which is exactly the situation you're dealing with.  So no, there isn't anything weird in the `constexpr` rules... it's the other older rules kicking in that have nothing to do with `constexpr`.

> A conditional-expression e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> ...
>
> - an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion unless it is applied to
>
>   - a non-volatile glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to a complete non-volatile const object with a preceding initialization, initialized with a constant expression, or
>   - a non-volatile glvalue that refers to a subobject of a string literal, or
>   - a non-volatile glvalue that refers to a non-volatile object deﬁned with `constexpr`, or that refers to a non-mutable subobject of such an object, or
>   - a non-volatile glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile object whose lifetime began within the evaluation of e;

You're right that the third subbullet does not apply.  But the first one does.

So you have an interesting interplay between new rules which allow function returns to be compile-time constant, depending on the rules for evaluation on the abstract machine, and the legacy behavior allowing integral values to be compile-time constant even if not marked as such.

---

Here's a quick example why it doesn't matter that `this` is an implicit argument.  Being an argument doesn't mean an object is evaluated:

```
constexpr int blorg(bool const flag, int const& input)
{
    return flag? 42: input;
}

int i = 5; // 5 is an integral constant expression, but `i` is not
constexpr int x = blorg(true, i); // ok, `i` was an argument but never evaluated
constexpr int y = blorg(false, i); // no way
```

For `std::integral_constant` member functions, you can consider `*this` like `i` in the `blorg` function -- if execution doesn't dereference it, it's ok for it to be passed around without being a compile-time constant.

Comment: I thought about this answer for a bit, to me it seems like if this answer is correct, my reasoning would be that `foo(0)` in my updated question should also compile, but it doesn't. I think understanding exactly the distinction between the two calls in my edit will answer the question clearly.

Comment: I think none of these applies because there is no  lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

Comment: @NirFriedman: In the cases that work, the only thing evaluated is an integral template parameter, which falls into subbullet 1.  In your new breaking code, a runtime variable parameter is evaluated.  Calling a non-virtual member function doesn't necessarily evaluate the expression on which it is invoked... `std::integral_constant` conversion operators don't access any non-static data members of `this`, and therefore don't become illegal in constant context.

Comment: @cpplearner: There is an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion in the failing `foo(0)` call.  But in the other, template-based code, there's only naming template parameters, which you are correct are not lvalues and therefore don't need to be converted.

Comment: @BenVoigt Right, ok. Then the key point (from my perspective) is that a constexpr member function not accessing `this` can be used in constant contexts, even if the object being called on is not a constant expression. This contradicts the naive interpretation that `this` is considered an implicit argument to all member functions. Can you find wording in the standard that supports this? If you do I'll accept.

Comment: @NirFriedman: An implicit argument can still be unused.  Does `foo(0)` fail if you change the body to not use the parameter?  e.g. `void foo2(int i) {
    constexpr std::size_t j = 42;
}`  Of course that will be ok.

Comment: Okay, good example. I'm honestly still finding this a bit confusing, but your explanation below the line helps quite a lot.

Answer (score 12):

The reason this works:

```
template <class T, class I>
auto foo(const T& t, I i) {
    return std::get<i>(t);
}
```

is because none of the reasons that it would fail apply. When `i` is a `std::integral_constant<size_t, S>`, `i` can be used as a converted constant expression of type `size_t` because that expression goes through `constexpr operator size_t()`, which simply returns a template parameter (which is a [prvalue](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#6.sentence-1)) as a value. That's a perfectly valid constant expression. Note that `this` is not referenced - just because it's a member function does not, in of itself, violate the constant expression constraint.

Basically, there's nothing "runtimey" about `i` here.

On the flip side, if `i` were an `int` (by way of `foo(0)`), then calling `std::get<i>` would involve an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion for `i`, but this case would not meet [any of the criteria](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2.7) since `i` does not have preceding initialization with a constant-expression, it is not a string literal, it wasn't defined with `constexpr`, and it didn't begin its lifetime in this expression.

Comment: Right, the important thing is that the value is extracted from the template parameter, not the function argument.

Comment: [A non-type non-reference template-parameter is a prvalue.](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#6.sentence-1)

Comment: I edited my question; as I commented below, the fact that `this` is not used does not matter by any naive interpretation of what member functions would do. Normally, a `constexpr` function requires *all* of its arguments to be constant expressions to be used as a constant expression. The situation with `this` is basically an exception, and there should be some language in the standard stating that this is ok.

Comment: @NirFriedman There's no exception - it's just that everything that you use in a constant expression has to be usable in a constant expression. If you don't use it, it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @Barry I better understand that now from Ben's example, thanks for explaining as well. I thought constexpr was more strict, definitely food for thought. I accepted Ben's because his example helped but upvoted yours as well, thanks again.

Comment: @NirFriedman Cheers. It's definitely not easy to understand since (a) the rules changed a lot since C++11 so you have to keep track of what worked when and (b) all the rules define what's disallowed rather than what's allowed, which makes things harder to think about.