# Using constant expressions as template parameter using a function parameter: which compiler is right?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20, constexpr

I have this piece of code right there:

```
template <int V>
struct Constant {
    constexpr operator int() const noexcept { return V; }
};


template <class T, int N>
struct Array { };

auto function(auto s) -> Array<int, s + s> {
    return {};
}

auto const a = function(Constant<3>{});
```

To my greatest sadness, only Clang seems to accept this code.

Which compiler is right, and why?

Comment: Function parameter are never constexpr. [Can't use function parameter of a constexpr function in a constant expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569309/cant-use-function-parameter-of-a-constexpr-function-in-a-constant-expression)

Comment: @user12002570 this is not true. Even if `s` is not constexpr, it is convertible to int at compile time, so `s` can be used in a constant expression.

Comment: See [Can't use function parameters of a constexpr function as template arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582875/cant-use-function-parameters-of-a-constexpr-function-as-template-arguments?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: There was no need to reopen this question. This has been asked more than 100 of times on stackoverflow.

Comment: @user12002570 Well, except this one is valid.

Comment: Looks like clang decays the `std::integral_constant` into the constant and then does the addition while gcc and MSVS just try to add the `integer_constant` which doesn't have an `operator +` so the template parameter is invalid.  Not sure who is right here but I feel it is gcc and MSVS since conversions are not supposed to be done in template argument deduction.

Comment: @user12002570 you are wrong. This question is a good one. I know exactly what I'm asking for. I will probably use the result of this question for reporting actual compiler bugs so they agree with each other if `s` decays to int at compile time or not.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot *" if s decays to int at compile time or not. "* That is the question.

Comment: @user12002570 I think I asked this right. `s + s` is indeed a constant expression. You can totally use `std::array<int, s + s>` in the body of the function, and all compiler accepts it: https://godbolt.org/z/jdMd9aoWb

Comment: interestingly MSVS will compile if the function is adjusted to take in a deduced `integral_constant` but uses that `integral_constant` to get the array size: https://godbolt.org/z/d7Tarz9f5. gcc still wont compile unless you use the deduced size: https://godbolt.org/z/6jo78xGqh

Comment: @NathanOliver clang seems to accept `std::array<int, s>` in the trailing return type too. I would actually expect clang to be right since all compiler accepts the expression inside the body of the function: https://godbolt.org/z/czs1MKs6s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe clang is correct here. Opened [#114124](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=114124) for gcc.

Note that both gcc and MSVC accept this equivalent formulation:

```cpp
auto function(auto s) {
    return Array<int, s+s>{};
}
```

It's just that they don't allow the use of the parameter in the return type.

But in the same way that writing `s+s` as a constant expression in the body of the function doesn't violate any rules of [[expr.const]/5](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5), no rules are violated in the trailing-return-type. We're just as much not reading anything (i.e. the usual reason such programs fail is because we're attempting an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on a value not known to the constant evaluator), since the conversion function to `int` is `constexpr` and doesn't rely on any data.

Comment: I opened this one for MSVC, I think it should cover it: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Terse-template-syntax-and-trailing-retur/10601951

Comment: @user12002570 That program is not ill formed and a ill formed program is not a valid reason to close a question anyway.

Comment: @user12002570 It is not an intuitition-based answer. I specifically noted that we're not violating any rules in [expr.const], which are the relevant ones here - it's a long list of things you are not allowed to do in a constant expression, none of which we're doing. It would be not be helpful to enumerate every rule we're *not* breaking in this program.

Comment: @user12002570 this explains why my program is actually valid: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46289082/2104697 the standardese is written there. The fact that you thought it was an ill-formed program was the intuition based conclusion. Barry answer is satisfactory enough for me.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot *"The fact that you thought it was an ill-formed program was the intuition based conclusion..."* No it was not intuition based as I had evidence(the dupes) for why I thought so. I clearly mentioned all the dupes in the comment section and closed the question as such.

Comment: as most comments seem to be deleted but the initial claim "Function parameter are never constexpr" persists, could you clarify if this statement is wrong or not? I am confused, because I have read it so often before

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai nothing of value was lost in those deleted comments. Function parameters cannot be used to initiate a compile time evaluation or nested compile time evaluation since they are not themselves marked as constexpr. In my example, despite it seems like I'm using `s` in `s + s`, the expression `s` is not evaluated and a new compile time evaluation is initiated.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot because `Array<T,N>` does not actually use `N`? Thats what you mean with "... is not evaluated .... " ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai in the evaluation of `Array<into, s>`, in the case where `s` is an integral constant, `s` is not being evaluated since the compiler decays `s` into an integral value, and the conversion operator is constexpr and do not dereference `this`, so it is evaluable at compile time.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai The statement is true: function parameters are not constexpr. However in this case, we're not reading the value of the parameter - we're using its (stateless) constexpr conversion function to `int`.

Comment: @Barry that made it click. Breaking it down to the trivial, it is similar to calling a const method to get a const value returned, you can do that on a non-const instance. `s` isnt `constexpr` but thats not that relevant